# comparator not calling in qsort [Error: expected expression before comparator]

Tags: c, arrays, structure, comparator, qsort

I am trying to call qsort with my comparator using an array of structures 'student'
It has the attributes:

```
typedef struct
{   
    int ID;                      // 4 bytes               = 164 [+ int]
    char firstname[NAME_LENGTH]; // 1 bytes * length (80) = 160 [2 * NAME_LENGTH]
    char lastname[NAME_LENGTH];  // 1 bytes * length (80)
} Student;
```

My code is attempting to call qsort from a function 3 times: to sort it by ID, then first name, then last name. The main function deals with calling other functions to reading and writing. Finding the error in one should make me able to apply it to the other function, right? However the functions involving sorting are:

```
#ifdef TEST_SORTID
void StudentSortbyID(Student * stu, int numelem)
{
    qsort(&(stu-> ID), numelem, sizeof(stu), compareInts);
}
#endif

#ifdef TEST_SORTFIRSTNAME
void StudentSortbyFirstName(Student * stu, int numelem)
{
    qsort(&(stu-> firstname), numelem, sizeof(stu), compareStrings);
}
#endif

#ifdef TEST_SORTLASTNAME
void StudentSortbyLastName(Student * stu, int numelem)
{
    qsort(&(stu-> lastname), numelem, sizeof(stu), compareStrings);
}
#endif

#ifdef TEST_COMPAREINTS
int compareInts(const void * argu1, const void * argu2)
{
    const int * iptr1 = (const int *) argu1;  //convert void to integer pointer
    const int * iptr2 = (const int *) argu2;
    int ival1 = * iptr1;                      //convert pointer to value
    int ival2 = * iptr2;
    if(ival1 < ival2)       { return -1; } //return -1 if first value is less
    if(ival1 > ival2)       { return 1; }  //return 1 if previous value is greater
    if(ival1 == ival2)      { return 0; }  //return 0 if the adjacent values are equal
}
#endif

#ifdef TEST_COMPARESTRINGS
int  compareStrings(const void * argu1, const void * argu1)
{
    //String is an array of characters (string = char*) -> pointing to string
    const char * const * sptr1 = (const char * *) argu1;  //converting empty pointers to strings which point to characters [**]
    const char * const * sptr2 = (const char * *) argu2;
    const char * string1 = * sptr1;                       // a string is a character pointer
    const char * string2 = * sptr2;
    return strcmp(string1,string2);
}
#endif
```

The error I am getting when running gcc is:

```
student.c:120: error: too few arguments to function ‘compareInts’
```

I thought qsort's comparator didn't take arguments? When I try to put in the 1st two elements of the array, it errors too. Any ideas?

Comment: And we are supposed not to sort out which lines the error message might relate to? Sorry, we are not a debugginmg service.

Comment: Do you declare the compare functions before the calls to qsort?

Comment: Sorry the error occurs at the line 4 @Olaf

Comment: And the functions are declared in a header file which is included @dromtrund

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to solve one thing after the other, i.e. start with sort by ID, provide a specific "sortStudentById"-comparator function, and start with a code without any `#ifdef` (these usually make debugging and understanding compiler errors more complicated).

I suppose one reason is that your compare function is not declared before it's usage in `qsort`.

Once you have solved this, you will for sure encounter the next problem in the usage of `qsort`. If you want to sort student objects, your compare function needs to take pointers to student objects (whereas qsort will repeatedly swap student objects as a whole, not pointers to them). Passing a pointer to a member to qsort (like `&(stu-firstname)`) will let qsort swap things in a way which is for sure not intended.

Try the following code as a starting point and make adaptions as required:

```
int compareStudentsByID(const void* s1, const void *s2) {
    return ((Student *)s1)->ID - ((Student*)s2)->ID;
}

void sortByID(Student *s) {

    qsort(s,100,sizeof(Student),compareStudentsByID);
}

int main() {

    Student students[100];
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        students[i].ID = rand()%1000;
    }
    sortByID (students);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remove the ifdef statements since they are used for partial credit grading.

The function is declared in a header file as:
int compareInts(const void * argu1, const void * argu2);
int compareStrings(const void * argu1, const void * argu2);

I am making the qsort adjustments however and I will let you know how it works!

Thank you!

Comment: I moved the functions before sorting function and modififed qsort and I am getting another familiar error. Undefined reference

Comment: I modified some more code and now the intereger one calls successfully (output i will check later) but the compare strings is not working saying i redefined parameter argu1. I should be able to tinker around and resolve the rest

Answer (score 0):

```
// Do not remove #ifdef ... #endif before and after each function.
// 
// They are used to test different functions in your program and give
// partial credits, in case your program does not work completely.

#include "student.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void StudentPrint(Student * stu, int num)
{
  printf("There are %d students\n", num);
  for (int ind = 0; ind < num; ind ++)
    {
      printf("ID = %d, First Name = %s, Last Name = %s\n",
         stu[ind].ID,  stu[ind].firstname, stu[ind].lastname);
    }
}

#ifdef TEST_READ
// return false if anything is wrong 
// return true if reading the file successfully and the data is save in
// the allocated memory
// input: filename, the name of the input file
// output: address of the allocated memory
// output: number of students
bool StudentRead(char * filename, Student * * stu, int * numelem)
{
    int id;
    char first[NAME_LENGTH];
    char last[NAME_LENGTH];
  // open the file to read
    FILE * inputPtr = fopen(filename, "r");

  // if fopen fails, return false
  // do not use fclose since fopen already fails
    if (inputPtr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File Opening failed; Evaluate read function\n");
        return false;
    }       

  // count the number of lines to determine the number of students
    while( 0 != fscanf(inputPtr, "\n")) { numelem++; }


  // return to the beginning of the file
  // you can use fseek or
  // fclose followed by fopen
  // You need to check whether fseek or fopen fails
  // Do not use rewind because it does not report whether it fails
    fclose(inputPtr);
    inputPtr = fopen(filename, "r");            // reading starts from 0

  // allocate memory for the data
    stu = malloc(((sizeof(*(stu))) * (*numelem)));

  // check whether memory allocation fails
    if (stu == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed; evaluate malloc\n");
        return false;
    }

  // read the data from the file and store the data in the allocated memory
    for (int count = 0; count < *numelem; count++)
    {
        fscanf(inputPtr, "%i %s %s\n", &id, &first[NAME_LENGTH], &last[NAME_LENGTH]);

        stu[count] -> ID = id;
        stu[count] -> firstname[NAME_LENGTH] = first[NAME_LENGTH];
        stu[count] -> lastname[NAME_LENGTH] = last[NAME_LENGTH];
    }
        if (stu[0] == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Inputting file values to variable failed; evluate read function\n");
        return false;
    }
  // close the file
fclose(inputPtr);

  return true;
}
#endif

#ifdef TEST_WRITE
// return false if anything is wrong 
// return true if writing the file successfully
// input: filename, the name of the output file
// input: address of the student array
// input: number of students

bool StudentWrite(char * filename, Student * stu, int numelem)
{

  // open the file to write 
    FILE * outputFile = fopen(filename, "w");

  // if fopen fails, return false
  // do not use fclose since fopen already fails
    if (outputFile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opening file failed; evaluate Write function\n");
        return false;
    }
  // write the students to the output file
    for (int count = 0; count < numelem; count++)
    {
        fprintf(outputFile, "%i %s %s\n", (stu[count]).ID, (stu[count]).firstname, (stu[count]).lastname);
    }
    return true;
}
#endif 

#ifdef TEST_SORTID
void StudentSortbyID(Student * stu, int numelem)
{
    qsort(stu, numelem, sizeof(Student), compareInts);
}
#endif

#ifdef TEST_SORTFIRSTNAME
void StudentSortbyFirstName(Student * stu, int numelem)
{
    qsort(stu -> firstname, numelem, sizeof(stu), compareStrings);
}
#endif

#ifdef TEST_SORTLASTNAME
void StudentSortbyLastName(Student * stu, int numelem)
{
    qsort(stu -> lastname, numelem, sizeof(stu), compareStrings);
}
#endif

int compareInts(const void * argu1, const void * argu2)
{
    const Student * iptr1 = (const Student *) argu1;  //convert void to integer pointer
    const Student * iptr2 = (const Student *) argu2;
    return iptr1 ->ID - iptr2 -> ID;
}

int  compareStrings(const void * argu1, const void * argu2)
{
    //String is an array of characters (string = char*) -> pointing to string
    const Student * sptr1 = (const char *) argu1;  //converting empty pointers to strings which point to characters [**]
    const Student * sptr2 = (const char *) argu2;
    const char string1 = sptr1 -> firstname;                          // a string is a character pointer
    const char string2 = sptr2 -> firstname;
    return strcmp(string1,string2);

}
```

This is the entire code for these functions. Another .c contains main

Comment: With this I am running into errors with the compare string function.
initializaiton from an incompatible pointer type among others.
I am attempting to fix them now

Comment: Code compiles now. Having trouble making my makefile but thats another topic